# How to obtain a variable number of arguments by "..." or by a list in R

Tags: r, list, function, variables, arguments

I made this helper function to compare variable number of input tables using calls to `janitor::compare_df_cols`.

Sometimes I have a namedlist of dataframes, and sometimes I may write their names directly when they are 2 or 3.

I want the helper function to get indistinctly either `...` or a `list()`, in all cases containing dataframes.

Ideally, I want `...` to convert into a named-list with names preserving those of the variables in the calling side passed as arguments. (Ex. people, people2, people3)

`...` gets unnamed and works different if conversion to `list()` is defined inside or outside the function.

EXAMPLE DATASET

```
lastnames <- LETTERS[1:4] ;   names  <- c("uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro"); 
age <- c(1:4)             ;   height <- seq(190,200,3)
people = data.frame(names, lastnames, age, height)
people2 = people %>% mutate( age = age + 20)
people3 = people; people3$height[[3]] = 160
```

HELPER FUNCTION

```
helper_df_compare = function( ..., a_default_arg="def" ){
    ##### Compare mismatching columns types
    ##### NOTE that, it does not checks contents
    rbind(
         janitor::compare_df_cols( ..., return="mismatch" ) %>%
                  mutate( column_name = paste("!!!", column_name) ),
         janitor::compare_df_cols( ..., return="match" )
         ) %>%
    mutate_all( ~str_replace_all(.,c(
      "integer"="int",   "numeric"="num",   "character"="chr",   "factor"="fct",
      "POSIXct, POSIXt"="POSIXct"
      ) ) )
}
```

INTENDED OPTIONAL CALLING METHODS

```
helper_df_compare( database_rnamedlist )             # <- preferred

helper_df_compare( list(people, people2, people3) )
helper_df_compare( people, people2, people3 )        # <- preferred

helper_df_compare( list("A"=people, "B"=people2, "C"=people3) )
helper_df_compare( A=people, B=people2, C=people3 )  # <- preferred
```

CURRENT OUTPUTs:
NOTE: column names should be the table name passed as argument

```
  column_name ..1_1 ..1_2 ..1_3
1     !!! age   int   num   int
2      height   num   num   num
3   lastnames   chr   chr   chr
4       names   chr   chr   chr

  column_name   A   B   C
1     !!! age int num int
2      height num num num
3   lastnames chr chr chr
4       names chr chr chr
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
  column_name people people2 people3
1     !!! age    int     num     int
2      height    num     num     num
3   lastnames    chr     chr     chr
4       names    chr     chr     chr

  column_name   A   B   C
1     !!! age int num int
2      height num num num
3   lastnames chr chr chr
4       names chr chr chr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the direct input of data frames, both named and unnamed, like this:

```r
helper_df_compare = function( ..., a_default_arg = "def" ){
  
  dots <- rlang::list2(...)
  args <- as.list(match.call())[-1]
  if(is.null(names(dots))) names(dots) <- rep('', length(dots))
  for(i in seq_along(dots)) {
    if(!nzchar(names(dots)[i])) names(dots)[i] <- as.character(args[[i]])
  }
   
   
    rbind(
         do.call(janitor::compare_df_cols, c(dots, return = "mismatch")) %>%
                  mutate( column_name = paste("!!!", column_name) ),
         do.call(janitor::compare_df_cols, c(dots, return = "match")) 
         ) %>%
    mutate_all( ~str_replace_all(.,c(
      "integer"="int",   "numeric"="num",   "character"="chr",   "factor"="fct",
      "POSIXct, POSIXt"="POSIXct"
      ) ) )
}
```

This allows

```
helper_df_compare(people, people2, people3)
#>   column_name people people2 people3
#> 1     !!! age    int     num     int
#> 2      height    num     num     num
#> 3   lastnames    chr     chr     chr
#> 4       names    chr     chr     chr
```

and this:

```r
helper_df_compare(A = people, B = people2, C = people3)
#>   column_name   A   B   C
#> 1     !!! age int num int
#> 2      height num num num
#> 3   lastnames chr chr chr
#> 4       names chr chr chr
```

Comment: Hi. Based in your introduction of `list2`. I found `dots_list()` and I finally got it working like this: `X <- rlang::dots_list(..., .named=TRUE);   X <- if ( length(X)==1 )  X[[1]]  else X`. The named arguments does the trick. But I was expecting something even shorter like `X = if (is.list(...)) ... else namedlist(...)` but this sentence is not allowed. Do you know any better approach?